# sage math: how to check if two expressions are equivalent?

Tags: math, sage

How can I determine in sage whether two expressions are equivalent? For example:

```
sage: var('x')
x
sage: e1 = 1 + x
sage: e2 = x + 1
sage: e3 = x + 2
sage: is_equivalent(e1, e2)
True
sage: is_equivalent(e1, e3)
False
sage: var('y')
y
sage: e4 = x * (1 + y)
sage: e5 = x + (x * y)
sage: is_equivalent(e4, e5)
True
sage: is_equivalent(e4, e1)
False
sage: assume(x, 'real')
sage: e6 = sqrt(x**2) + 1
sage: is_equivalent(e6, e1)
True
```

**What has already been suggested/ tried:** (*sage 6.4.1 on Ubuntu Linux*)

```
sage: e1 == e2
x + 1 == x + 1
sage: e1 is e2
False
sage: e1.match(e2) is not None
True
sage: e4.match(e5) is not None
False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to make an equation out of them and check whether it is `True` or `False`.

```
sage: e4 == e5
x*(y + 1) == x*y + x
sage: bool(_)
True
```

However, keep in mind that Sage will return `False` if it cannot prove it is `True`, which is not the same thing as *being* false.  Checking equivalence of two arbitrary expressions might be arbitrarily long to do, and might require a crazy sequence of expansions/'simplifications' the computer cannot predict.

This is answering a different question:

```
sage: e1 is e2
False
```

This is Python, and is a very strong condition that two things are the same "object", which in this case they aren't.

```
sage: a = 1
sage: b = 1
sage: a is b
False
sage: a = 1
sage: b = a
sage: a is b
True
```

Comment: There is no better way, such as one that specifies the vars are rational numbers?  For example, why doesn't this work (seems simple enough): `bool((x^2)^(1/2) == x)`

Comment: I am familiar with python but tried "is" as a last resort. I searched the docs but got way too many results. By any chance, do you happen to know where in the sage docs I should have looked to find this?

Comment: Well, I have to say that it is there but not organized as well as possible.  The symbolic expression documentation is probably where it's best laid out.